# If I have used "On the one hand", do I need to write "on the other hand" somewhere after?

Tags: idioms

I am an English learner in mainland China. I have a question regarding the structure "On the one hand... On the other hand" and would really appreciate it if anyone can elucidate this point.

Please mind that I already know from other posts that "On the other hand" can be used independently without a previous "On the one hand".

My question is: if I have already used "on the one hand", do I have to use "on the other hand" later? Or is it okay to use "on the one hand" followed by contrasting phrases like "by contrast"?

Comment: "On the other hand" is by no means absolutely required.

Comment: @MattSamuel Very true, but there must be a second element to the discussion prefixed in some other way such as _otherwise_ or, as the OP says, _by contrast_. Without the second element the use of _on the one hand_ would be illogical. Also I would say that any argument introduced with _on the one hand_ should be binary as humans have, at most, two hands; if more than two options are discussed then the first one should be introduced using a form like _firstly_ or _first of all_.

Comment: @BoldBen I wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: Please look up a good resource online and let us know what you found. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris In this case, I'm not sure what kind of resource would definitively answer OP's question, or even how he'd go about searching. No, the question is fine so far as background research goes, but is probably too subjective (which is one reason I believe it'll be hard to find a resource that answers it; it's a question of style, not canon).

Comment: On one hand... On the other hand... is a common construction. If not explicitly stated, the first hand is often assumed. It is considered bad form to go up to three or four hands.

Comment: On the one hand,  you can write whatever you want. By contrast, I wouldn't use the phrase 'on the one hand' without using 'on the other hand'; it sounds strange. A native speaker of English is going to expect 'on the other hand'.

Comment: Chinese has a construct along the lines of *not only ... but also*. If you only have the *not only* part but not the *but also* part, it doesn't 'feel' right. The *on the one hand ... on the other* construct is similar - I'd go so far as to say that it's incomplete if you leave out *on the other* (or some variant thereof).

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - If you're an SF fan, and have read Jerry Pournelle/Larry Niven's "Mote in God's Eye" books, you'll be familiar with "On the one hand...,on the other hand...,on the gripping hand".

Comment: I doubt that Captain Hook ever said "on the other hand."

Answer (score 2):

The usual construction in the English (or any similar) language would be:

*On the one hand... On the other [hand]...* — [Cambridge Dict.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-the-one-hand-on-the-other-hand)

> *"On the one hand I'd like a job that pays more, but on the other hand I enjoy the work I'm doing at the moment."*

Sometimes, we do not explicitly state "on the one hand", but it is often assumed.

The following [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20the%20one%20hand%2Con%20the%20other%20hand&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Con%20the%20one%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20one%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20one%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Con%20the%20other%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20other%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20other%20hand%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Con%20the%20one%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20one%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20one%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Con%20the%20other%20hand%3B%2Cc1%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20other%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20other%20hand%3B%2Cc0) shows that "on the other hand" is used more frequently than "on the one hand".

[image: Google Ngrams]

On the other hand, using "on the one hand" without "on the other hand" will sound odd, or illogical, to a native speaker at least. There may not be any rules regarding this other than general usage trends.

Comment: I noticed that you put the word "hand" in the square brackets, does it imply that you may even simply say "on the other" without "hand" when the two relevant sentences are very close to each other?

Comment: @gamebm well on the one hand, it's good to complete the phrase as it is, and on the other, you can remove words from commonly used expressions and still convey the same message